# Apache Ignite .Net Client Server Connection

Tags: c#, .net, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite .Net.I have created two separate web applications with Apache Ignite from Nuget. One application set as client using 
clientMode = true
But I dont know how to connect this two application using ip, port etc. Please help me...
Please note both applications are run on localhost.
[I have tried with this link](https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/v2.0/docs/clients-and-servers)

I haven't added any config details of Ignite in client web.config.

**My web.config for server :**

```
   <configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="igniteConfiguration" type="Apache.Ignite.Core.IgniteConfigurationSection, Apache.Ignite.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <runtime>
    <gcServer enabled="true" />
  </runtime>
  <igniteConfiguration xmlns="http://ignite.apache.org/schema/dotnet/IgniteConfigurationSection"
                        localhost="127.0.0.1" peerAssemblyLoadingMode="CurrentAppDomain">
    <atomicConfiguration atomicSequenceReserveSize="10" />

    <discoverySpi type="TcpDiscoverySpi">
      <ipFinder type="TcpDiscoveryMulticastIpFinder">
        <endpoints>
          <string>127.0.0.1:47500..47502</string>
        </endpoints>
      </ipFinder>
    </discoverySpi>
  </igniteConfiguration>
</configuration>
```

**My Server Code for start Ignite:**

```
IIgnite ignite = Ignition.StartFromApplicationConfiguration();
```

**Client application hangs at code :**

```
Ignition.Start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignite nodes will connect to each other with default configuration, you don't need to change anything.

Either remove `discoverySpi` from configuration on both client and server, or make sure that configuration is the same.

Also note that client node will hang if there are no server nodes.

Comment: Edited my answer.